# What is an idiomatic usage of header.Write/WriteSubset?

Tags: http, go, http-headers

Go's `http.Header` has these two methods:

- [`Header.Write(io.Writer)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Write)
- [`Header.WriteSubset(io.Writer, exclude map[string]bool)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.WriteSubset)

I see that the standard library uses these methods for example when writing request headers, but why are they public/what is a standard use case?

Comment: Looks like they're still [discussing this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16479). I'm not sure there's a good reason, beyond being header methods.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would want to export anything that some other package needs to call. Sometimes this can get fairly low-level.

`Header.WriteSubset()` would be useful in writing an HTTP proxy. The HTTP specifications say that certain headers are hop-by-hop headers, so that proxies that receive them must not pass them on to the next hop. By contrast, end-to-end headers are always passed on.

There are probably other uses. `httputil.DumpRequest()` uses `WriteSubset()` to exclude some irrelevant headers from its output.

Exporting `Header.Write()` is less obvious. Though the Go standard library uses it to implement its CGI and FastCGI servers.